# Should 127.0.0.1 and ::1 both be included in /etc/hosts file?

Tags: hosts-file

I am new to unmanaged VPS servers and in addition IPv6.  Is it necessary to include 127.0.0.1 AND ::1 for localhost in /etc/hosts files for IPv6 enabled servers, or is ::1 alone enough?

Comment: https://github.com/lennylxx/ipv6-hosts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, 127.0.0.1 should be left. IPv6 is enabled, but IPv4 is still used.

Comment: So I should include the following in my hosts file?

127.0.0.1 localhost
::1       localhost

Comment: Yes, you should keep both the ipv4 and ipv6 localhost addresses

Comment: Here's another reason you should keep both on Windows: [Fix Google Chrome slow or hanging resolving host](https://markshust.com/2019/12/17/fix-google-chrome-slow-hanging-resolving-host/)

Answer (score 5):

You didn't mention which OS you are using.

On Windows systems, the name resolution of `localhost` is handled by the system and those entries are not needed in the `hosts` file. This is even explicitly mentioned in that very same file:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

Comment: "is handled by the system", but how do I configure it? Where can I find the DNS settings which handles localhost name resolution? (in my case I'm running Windows 10)

Comment: is handled by the system, but where ? in which file at which level? Best regards.

Answer (score 4):

Leave the hosts file alone. Fiddle with it and you may break something. For example, if you remove the `127.0.0.1` don't be too surprised if anything that uses `localhost` fails.

Comment: I was curious about 120.0.0.1 and ::1 because I had never seen ::1 before and it (along with an IPv6 address) were the only things in my hosts file.  Ended up cleaning things up a bit to include 127.0.0.1 as well.

Comment: @filmoreha, I suspect that's a typo but there was no mention of 120.0.0.1. You also need to consider that a hosted environment, even an unmanaged one, will have certain requirements for monitoring purposes, which is another reason to be cautious of modifying things like the hosts file.

Comment: Thanks, that was definitely a typo.  I will keep what you said about monitoring in mind, hadn't thought about that!

Answer (score 0):

Adding anything to /etc/hosts is not necessary, but really helps, so it will be pretty useful to add both (IPv4 and IPv6) records. After all, it is not expensive in any sense (10 seconds on each won't kill you day), but you'll know this part is done completely.

Answer (score -2):

On my mac, I could not access localhost. When I commented out the line "::1     localhost", I was able to access localhost again.